# Group theory: $[H/K,J/K]=[H,J]/K$ or $[HK/K,JK/K]=[H,J]K/K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I wrote a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1890391/g-k-is-solvable-iff-gn%E2%8A%86k) which deals with solvability and commutator subgroup. In the answer I got I was told to proof that $$[HK/K,JK/K]=[H,J]K/K$$

the problem I have is that proving this is the same to me as proving $$[H/K,J/K]=[H,J]/K$$

which in the context of my problem has no sense because from here I get to $(G/K)^{n)} = G^{n)}/K = 1$ and then  $G^{n)} = K$ while I should be getting $G^{n)} \subseteq K$.

Can anybody show how proving these two things is different? I'm confused with all the cosets and generators involved.

Comment: $[H,J]/K$ only makes sense if $K$ is a subgroup of $[H,J]$, which it need not be.

Comment: Go back to studying cosets, factor groups. If $H$ is a subgroup of the group $G$, and $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then $HN/N$ is the corresponding subgroup in the factor group $G/N$, in fact the image of $H$ of the canonical epimorphism $G \rightarrow G/N$. $H/N$ makes no sense in general, unless $N \subseteq H$.